# Code motion optimization of trigonometric function[cos(\theta)]

Tags: optimization, trigonometry

As we know that trigonometric functions take more cpu cycles. If we want to lessen the cpu cycles, then we need to apply some optimizations.

I have a code like this:

```
for(i=0; i<n; i++)
{
   for(j=i+1; j<n; j++)
   {
       val1 = some value after calculation
       val2 = cos(val1);
   }
}
```

Now I need to optimize(specially code motion optimization) the cos() function, so that it will take less cpu cycle.

Hint: We can use two array of size n.

Comment: Are you trying to solve a problem or is this some type of trivia?

Comment: @Marty looks like homework

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming

Comment: Well, since you're clearly never using `val2`, you can optimize your code to `;`. In all seriousness, without knowing more, there's no obvious way to hoist. Also, what have you tried or even just considered?

Comment: You don't tell us much. What is val1 ? Is its value dependent on both i and j ? Can you accept loss of accuracy ?

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way is to precompute the results to the desired precision and use a lookup table.